# Java class cast exception with List<Object>

Tags: java, mysql

I try to get result from a mysql query and store it in an object, but i have a class cast exception, I work in a Java project with mysql.

The query works fine, and I get the results stored in the `r list<Object>`

Here is my code:

```
List<QReport> result = new ArrayList<QReport>();
    try {
        List<Object> r  = boomFacade.getEm().createNativeQuery("SELECT boom.name, boom.date, boom.type "
       + "FROM boom "
       + "where boom.type = 'REQUESTED' "
       + "AND boom.boomNumber = ? "
       + "AND boom.date >= ? "
       + "AND boom.date <= ? "
       + "ORDER BY boom.name, boom.id")
       .setParameter(1, boomNumber)     
       .setParameter(2, start)      
       .setParameter(3, end)    
       .getResultList();

        for (Object l: r){
            List<Object> ls = (ArrayList<Object>) l; // Class cast execption here
            QReport report = new QReport();
            report.setName((String) ls.get(0));
            Date eventDate = new Date( ((Timestamp)ls.get(1)).getTime());
            report.setDate(eventDate);
            report.setType((String) ls.get(2));
            result.add(report);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

The error log is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Comment: Based on the error, `l` is an `Object[]`, not a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Whatever the object is, it isn't a list.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have an `Object[]` (an array of `Object`), which you are trying to cast to an `ArrayList<Object>`. An array is not a list, so you can't cast it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is not clear what kind of thing a "boom" is. But it seems very clear that either your database structure or your hibernate mappings or both are not very reasonable. If you do it right, you should not have to manually poke around in your results and paste together your desired object like in good old JDBC. Avoiding such boilerplate code is the very reason people invented frameworks like hibernate. 
If you are not sure how to do the mapping right, this would be a good question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/

You're performing a cast on that line that is completely unneeded and out of context.

You can convert an `Object[]` to a `List<Object>` with: `Arrays.asList(l);`